# How to Expand Server Storage to Dell PowerEdge With a SAN?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2016, storage-area-network

I have recently bought Dell Poweredge T410 server with a Perc 6/I RAID controller to get some hands on experience  with server hardware and play around with Windows Server OSs.

I've been looking at expanding storage with a PowerVault MD1000 or MD3000 as I already have some virtual machines on my personal PC and it would be nice to utilise the server for these virtual machines instead.

What I'm confused with is, what card and cables do I need to connect the SAN to the server?

Many thanks

Will

Comment: ask dell, they give you also the right answer. trust me ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the storage array you've got in mind.

A passive SAS enclosure (usually with an integrated expander) requires a SAS RAID controller. A SAS array requires a SAS HBA (it uses the RAID functionality inside the applicance). Both are Direct Attached Storage/DAS, but can potenially be shared across hosts when they feature multiple host ports or through an expander.

A Storage Area Network/SAN uses either Fibre Channel or iSCSI. Fibre Channel requires an FC HBA and iSCSI some kind of initiatior - either a NIC with hardware iSCSI initiator or and simple NIC with the software initiatior included with Win2016.

SAN arrays have the advantage of being accessible by multiple hosts when connected through a switch. iSCSI can be connected across an Ethernet network and it can even be routed between networks.